# Going from one instance of string.find to the next

Tags: c++, string, replace

Well, this is another classic puzzle... My goal is to take the first letter of each word in a string and put it at the end of that word adding -ay (Pig Latin). I managed to transform the first word. But how do I move on to the next? I consulted different sources, forums but I am still stuck... Any tips? :) Maybe something like: **pos = a.find(" ", pos +1)**? See code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()

{
    std::string a = "hello what is going on";
    std::string b = "ay ";
    std::size_t pos = a.find(" ");
    int length = a.length();
    std::string first = a.substr(0,1);

        for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
        {   
            if (pos != std::string::npos)
                {
                a.replace(pos, a.length(), first + b);   //I guess I have to change sth. here.
                }                                        //Maybe a while-loop?
        }

    a.replace(0, 1, "");
    std::cout << a;            //Output: "ellohay"; **goal**: "ellohay hatway siay oingay noay"
    
}
```

Comment: I would split the string into a vector of strings an manipulate each string in a loop

Comment: Well, you already know most of the answer. What happened when you tried something like `pos = a.find(" ", pos +1)`?

Comment: Also, [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin#Rules) is not as simple as that.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: something like this came out: ellohayhayhayhayhayhayhayhayhayhayhayh.  :)

Comment: @Thomas Sablik: I will try that out. Need to do some reading on how to do this though since I haven't worked with vectors yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

Just tokenize the string, take each token, save the first char of token in some var, remove the first char and build what you need.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  // build istringstream object from provided text
  auto input = istringstream{"hello what is going on"};

  string token = "";
  string output = "";

  // tokenize provided text input
  while(input >> token) {
    char first = token[0]; // save the first char of token
    token.erase(0, 1); // remove the first char from token
    output = output + token + first + "ay" + " "; // build what you need
  }

  // okay, print output to check if everything is okay
  cout << output << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
ellohay hatway siay oinggay noay
```

[P.S.]: feel free to ask, if you have any question regarding this code/solution method.

Answer (score 3):

As so often with string-manipulation tasks, it is *so much* easier to keep separate "source" and "destination" strings, rather than trying to modify a single string "on the fly".

For your case, the following `PigLatin` function does what you ask (though I'm not here attempting to validate your definition of Pig Latin). It also handles multiple spaces between words and has a code block to handle characters that aren't letters or spaces, which you can modify as you see fit.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string PigLatin(std::string & input)
{
//  if (input.empty()) return ""; // Not sure what you want to do with empty strings?
    std::string answer = "";
    bool inword = false;
    char firstc = ' '; // Never used unitialized, but give it a value to silence the warning
    for (auto testc : input) {
        if (std::isspace(testc)) { // Space: check if we have a current word...
            if (inword) {          // ... and add last char + "ay" if we do
                answer += firstc;
                answer += "ay";
            }
            inword = false;        // Flag that we are now outside a word
            answer += testc;       // And add this space to the answer.
        }
        else if (std::isalpha(testc)) { // Letter: Check if it's the first in a word...
            if (!inword) firstc = testc; // If so, store it for future use
            else answer += testc;        // Otherwise append to the answer
            inword = true;
        }
        else { // Non-alpha, non-space ...
            answer += testc;
        }
    }
    // Handle terminal case, where we have a word without a space after it:
    if (inword) {
        answer += firstc;
        answer += "ay";
    }
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "hello ... what is   going on";
    std::string b = PigLatin(a);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: I like this code because you use the "basic" techniques (if, else, etc.). I'm still pretty new to coding (started a few months ago) so I have not used some of the parts in the code like std::isspace or std::isalpha. Thank you for the ideas!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do what you want using standard algorithms:

```cpp
std::ostringstream result;  // to store the result

std::istringstream iss{a};  // convert string to stream

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss}, 
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>{},    
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{result},
               [&b](auto const &word) {
                   return word.substr(1) + word[0] + b;   // pig latin
               });

std::cout << result.str();  // convert output stream to string
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6qs4Kj).

Comment: Thank you cigien! This seems to be the most compact solution :) Now I just need to figure out what all the different parts actually do...

Comment: @BisAndiGrenzen Take a look at [transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), and [istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to all of you I came up with some sort of "mixed" implementation of your ideas, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()

{
    std::string a = "hello what is going on";
    std::string b = "ay ";
    std::string c = "ay";
    std::string delimiter = " ";
    std::size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    std::string output = "";
    

    while ((pos = a.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        token = a.substr(0, pos);
        char first = token[0];
        token.replace(pos, token.length(), first + b);
        token.erase(0, 1);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        a.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    char firstA = a[0];
    a.erase(0, 1);
    
    std::cout << a + firstA + c  << std::endl;
}
```

Not sure if advanced programmers would disapprove of that solution...
Again: thank you very much!!